# Creating a duplicate service using AddHostedService<T>()

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code, how can I create two (or more) Worker services? I'm not looking to create a second Worker class. Is there a way to utilize DI and create a second Worker instance?

**Program.cs**

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyNamespace;

var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterType<WorkerDep>().As<IWorkerDep>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<Worker>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

**Worker.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

public class Worker : BackgroundService 
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IWorkerDep _dep;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IWorkerDep dep)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dep = dep;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _dep.Print();
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkerDep.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

public class WorkerDep : IWorkerDep
{
   private int _counter = 0;
   public void Print()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("WorkerDep: " + _counter++);
   }
}
```

**IWorkerDep.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

public interface IWorkerDep
{
   public void Print();
}
```

Comment: This will likely be less about Autofac and more about how `AddHostedService` works. You need the service hosting engine to recognize two different instances of the same thing; Autofac is going to be a potential means to an end. You may not get the eyes on this question that you need by framing it as an Autofac question.

Comment: Thank you for that response. I will take that into account. Do you believe I should adjust the title and take out the tag.

Comment: I'd recommend adjusting the title and making sure you have something about hosted services as a tag. (I don't have any specific recommendations, sorry.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a reported issue in .NET core:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38751

The easiest way around it is to replace the call:

```
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

to:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(worker);
```